# Is there a way to store launch configs from a POM file so they can be imported into Eclipse and Idea?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, intellij-idea

My team develops Java and Scala applications. Until recently the entire team has used Eclipse to develop. All projects (Scala included) use Maven to manage dependencies and builds and the POM is the defacto project definition. A few of our applications have a lot of VM and Program arguments necessary for launching the application.

Until now these parameters were just recorded in a launch config in Eclipse. Some of the developers have started switching to IntelliJ Idea. We can import a Maven project easily enough in both IDEs and developers have the freedom to choose their preferred IDE without any difficult. However, the launch configurations are not stored in the POM file.

An ideal solution would allow Eclipse and Idea to import these launch configurations from the POM file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can configure [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) in your `pom.xml` and then setup maven launch in idea, eclipse or run it from command-line or any other IDE.